# Qual é a origem e significado da expressão: "com a regularidade de um relógio suíço"?

Tags: etimologia, significado-em-contexto

Há tempos estava a ler um jornal de desporto e tinha algo escrito mais ou menos como: ele faz isso com **a regularidade de um relógio suíço**.

Comment: A expressão existe em inglês também - se foi importada, valeria a pena perguntar sobre a origem no English Language SE.

Comment: Pode até ser um caso de convergência na linguagem... afinal, funcionar como um relógio é uma clara referência.

Answer (score 4):

Aqui no Brasil usamos muito a expressão "como um relógio" ou "como um reloginho".

A expressão indica que algo funciona com exatidão. É muito comum as pessoas falarem "Meu intestino funciona como um reloginho". O que significa que elas vão ao banheiro regularmente e sempre nos mesmos horários, ou logo após uma refeição. Há outros usos para essa expressão, mas certamente a mais comum é essa.

Quando adicionamos "um relógio suíço", é para enfatizar o quão preciso é algo, pois pelo menos aqui, os relógios suíços são reconhecidos como peças de altíssima qualidade.

Como exemplo, [esse texto](https://www.otk.com.br/blog/o-que-um-relogio-suico-pode-ensinar-sobre-gestao-empresarial/) sobre gestão empresarial faz referência à expressão "como um relógio suíço", veja: "a referência a um antigo relógio mecânico é devido à precisão que cada componente foi projetado, fabricado e montado para funcionar com exatidão absoluta. É deste modo perfeito de projetar, fabricar e fazer funcionar as minúsculas engrenagens de forma tão sincronizada que se originou a expressão “como um relógio suíço”."

Comment: O @Thai, boa a tua resposta. Poderias procurar alguma referência para suportar a tua resposta?

Comment: Minha resposta partiu de conhecimento geral... Procurei agora uma bibliografia, mas encontrei apenas referências à expressão e explicações tão informais quanto a minha.

Comment: Como exemplo, esse texto sobre gestão empresarial faz referência à expressão "como um relógio suíço", veja: " referência a um antigo relógio mecânico é devido a precisão que cada componente foi projetado, fabricado e montado para funcionar com exatidão absoluta. É deste modo perfeito de projetar, fabricar e fazer funcionar as minúsculas engrenagens de forma tão sincronizada que se originou a expressão “como um relógio suíço”."
https://www.otk.com.br/blog/o-que-um-relogio-suico-pode-ensinar-sobre-gestao-empresarial/

Comment: ótimo, pode alterar tua respota e adicionar o trecho do texto com a referência?

Comment: "Como é o funcionamento do seu intestino?" é uma pergunta que faço diariamente em meu consultório.  E "funciona como um relógio" é uma resposta comum.  Já no diminutivo, "como um reloginho", eu nunca ouvi.  Talvez um pediatra ouça a resposta no diminutivo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, ficou bem clarificado.